# What's wrong in this integration equation?

Tags: calculus, integration

does anyone know what's wrong in this expression?

$$ \int_0^a f(a - x) \; \mathrm d x = \int f(0) \; \mathrm dx - \int f(a)  \;\mathrm dx = \int_a^0 f(x) \; \mathrm dx $$

I tested values and it's indeed wrong. It's supposed to have a minus sign, but I don't see which step has error.. :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you mean $\int_0^a f'(a-x)dx = f(0)-f(a) = -\int_0^a f'(x) dx$ or something like this?

Comment: @Guest86 nop, there's no derivative

Comment: anything else you forgot to mention about $f$? why do you think these equalities hold?

Comment: @Guest 86 well isn't the middle part the expansion of the definite integral in the first part?

Comment: No, the middle part is nonsense. If you set $u=a-x$, then $du=-dx$. Also, when $x=0$, you have $u=a$; and when $x=a$, you have $x=0$. After substitution, the integral on the left becomes $-\int_a^0 f(u)\,du$; which is the negative of the integral on the right.

Comment: In the middle you have two indefinite integrals of constants, while on the ends you have definite integrals.  Huh?

Comment: Here's what you may be thinking: For integrable $f$, if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then $G(x)=-F(a-x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(a-x)$. The integral on the left is $G(a)-G(0) $. But $G(a)-G(0)=-F(0) - (-F(a))=F(a)-F(0)=\int_0^a f(x)\,dx=-\int_a^0 f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Not quite sure what he was trying to represent with that middle term, but it may have been an incorrect form of this: $\int^b_af(z)dz=F(b)-F(a)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's take it one step at a time:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^a f(a - x) d x &= - \int_a^0 f(y) d y \qquad \text{by \(y = a - x\), \(d y = - dx\)} \\
                      &= \int_0^a f(y) d y   \qquad \text{turn around limits}
\end{align*}
$$
Your derivation works if $f(a - x) = f(a) - f(x)$, and that isn't always true.